# snakemake dry run for a single wildcard in order of execution

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to do a dry run for snakemake for a **single** wildcard, in the order of execution?

When I call a dry run, I get the following at the bottom:

```
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       assembly_eval
        5       cat_fastq
        1       createGenLogDir
        5       createLogDir
        5       flye
        5       medaka_first
        5       medaka_second
        5       minimap_first
        5       quast_medaka_first
        5       quast_medaka_second
        5       quast_racon_first
        5       racon_first
        5       symLinkFQ
        58
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

So I guess it would be useful to:

1. get the dry run commands for a **single** wildcard (except for the aggregate rules, obviously), after all, the only thing that differs among the commands of any of those rules is the wildcard in the input, output and param directives.
2. get the workflow printed in the order of execution, for enhanced visualisation.

I did not find a suitable option using `snakemake -h`, and I'd be looking for something that `--rulegraph`, does compared `--dag`, which is to avoid redundancy.

If there is no solution to this, or if the solution is too cumbersome, I guess I will suggest this as enhancement in their github page.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible solutions:

- You can specify a target file with the specific wildcard you want, e.g. `snakemake -nq output_wc1.txt`
- If your wildcards are stored in a list/dataframe, limit to just the first.  I frequently do this while developing, e.g. `chroms = range(1,2)  # was range(1, 23)`

If you have a single job for each rule and dependencies are simple (A -> B -> C), the jobs should be listed in order of execution.  This is not true when your workflow has concurrent or branching rules.

Have you also checked `--filegraph` and `--summary`?

Comment: the method I have been using is indeed to limit the number of wildcards e.g `wildcards = wildcards[:1]`, although I wanted to avoid hard-coding the snakefile. Specifying `output_wc1.txt` is an option as well. It is true that the commands are printed in order of execution, except for that summary I have on my question.